# How to Solve for $x$ and $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$-5x+2y=-25  $$
$$-2x+5y=11$$

Please help me solve for $x$ and $y$.

I came up with
$$x+y=12$$
but that didn't help.

Comment: Solve the second equation for $y$ since $x$ is absent. Then, use the first equation for $x$.

Comment: Should there be an $x$ in the second equation?

Comment: @mapierce271 I was wondering the same thing; otherwise, it seems like a pretty pointless exercise.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. Could you please tell us why you (downvoters) downvoted the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use elimination. Since multiplying an equation by a non-zero number does not change its solution set, we can multiply one or both equations by a non-zero number so that we can eliminate a variable through addition or subtraction.

\begin{alignat*}{3}   
-5x & + & 2y & = -25 \tag{1}\\
-2x & + & 5y & = 11 \tag{2}
\end{alignat*}

Multiply equation 1 by $5$ and equation $2$ by $-2$ to obtain

\begin{alignat*}{3}   
-25x & + & 10y & = -125 \tag{3}\\
4x & - & 10y & = -22 \tag{4}
\end{alignat*}
Adding equations 3 and 4 yields
$$-21x = -147 \tag{5}$$
Solve equation 5 for $x$, then substitute the value of $x$ you obtain into equation 1 or equation 2 to determine $y$.  Verify your solution is correct by substituting the values you obtain for $x$ and $y$ in equations 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$-2+5y=11 \Leftrightarrow 5y = 13 \Leftrightarrow y = \dfrac{13}{5}.$$

Now substitute this into the first equation to get the desired answer.

Comment: Why the downvote ... ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the question. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 2):

$-2+5y=11 \implies y=\frac{11+2}5 \implies y=\frac {13}5$

So,

$-5\cdot x + 2\cdot \frac{13}5 = -25  \implies -5\cdot x = -25 - \frac{26}5 \implies x=5-26/25 \implies x=-1/25$

Comment: PS: use \Rightarrow for $\Rightarrow$, \cdot for $\cdot$, and \frac{a}{b} for $\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the question. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have $-5x+2y=-25$ and $-2x+5y=11$. An easy way to handle this would be to manipulate both equations into having a zero on the right-hand side: $-5x+2y+25=0$ and $-2x+5y-11=0$. Thus, we can set them equal to each other:
$$
-2x+5y-11=-5x+2y+25,
$$
from which we see that
$$
5y-2y=2x-5x+36\Longleftrightarrow 3y=-3x+36 \Longleftrightarrow y = -x+12.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Since you changed the problem, extract, say, $x$ from the first equation expressing it as a function of $y$. Plug the result in the second equation; solve it for $y$. Go back to $x$ to get its value.